# FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml deserialize mixed ordered tag

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have xml from the customer:

```
<a>
   <b id="id1"/>
   <any-tag/>
   <b id="id2"/>
</a>
```

And simple Java class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;

@ToString
public class A {

    @ToString
    public static class B {
        public String id;
    }


    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "b")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List<B> bList;
}
```

When Jackson finish parsing I have result

```
A(bList=[A.B(id=id2)])
```

It is evident that I only got the second tag, but expected 2 tags in *bList*. I realized that this is due to the fact that *any-tag* tag is between the first and second tag B.

How I can read all B tags in list? PS Tag A contains other content that should also be read.

I'm using:

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1',
'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.5.1',
'org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.1.4',
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.9, **@JsonMerge** annotation was introduced.
The following would aggregate each occurrence of node **b** into bList:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "b") 
@JsonMerge() 
public List<B> bList;
```